# How to change format of input type="datetime-local" to dd/mm/yyyy --:-- -- jquery or html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have value timestamp database.

i want change format input type="datetime-local" from mm-dd-yyyy --:-- -- to dd/mm/yyyy --:-- -- using jquery or js or html tag?

Comment: Inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date